# Running in to werkzeug.exceptions.ClientDisconnected when using gunicorn

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, werkzeug

I am using Gunicorn wsgi server to serve my flask application in production.
Command to kick start the application is

```
gunicorn -t600 --workers 2 --max-requests 1200 --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 index:app
```

The server often throws the following exception.

```
werkzeug.exceptions.ClientDisconnected: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

I checked the [issue](https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/3448) in the flask repository. The suggestion is to not use the Werkzeug wsgi server in production as it doesn't drain the input.

I can't seem to figure out why I am running into the same problem when running my application with gunicorn. Here is the full stack trace of the exception.

```
Sep 29 10:14:56 ip-10-2-1-136 gunicorn[16388]:     loggerInfo('request.files={}'.format(request.files))
Sep 29 10:14:56 ip-10-2-1-136 gunicorn[16388]:   File "/home/ubuntu/ca/venv_dc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 347, in __getattr__
Sep 29 10:14:56 ip-10-2-1-136 gunicorn[16388]:     return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
Sep 29 10:14:56 ip-10-2-1-136 gunicorn[16388]:   File "/home/ubuntu/ca/venv_dc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/utils.py", line 90, in __get__
Sep 29 10:14:56 ip-10-2-1-136 gunicorn[16388]:     value = self.func(obj)
Sep 29 10:14:56 ip-10-2-1-136 gunicorn[16388]:   File "/home/ubuntu/ca/venv_dc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers/base_request.py", line 514, in files
Sep 29 10:14:56 ip-10-2-1-136 gunicorn[16388]:     self._load_form_data()
Sep 29 10:14:56 ip-10-2-1-136 gunicorn[16388]:   File "/home/ubuntu/ca/venv_dc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/wrappers.py", line 88, in _load_form_data
Sep 29 10:14:56 ip-10-2-1-136 gunicorn[16388]:     RequestBase._load_form_data(self)
Sep 29 10:14:56 ip-10-2-1-136 gunicorn[16388]:   File "/home/ubuntu/ca/venv_dc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers/base_request.py", line 319, in _load_form_data
Sep 29 10:14:56 ip-10-2-1-136 gunicorn[16388]:     self._get_stream_for_parsing(), mimetype, content_length, options
Sep 29 10:14:56 ip-10-2-1-136 gunicorn[16388]:   File "/home/ubuntu/ca/venv_dc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 232, in parse
Sep 29 10:14:56 ip-10-2-1-136 gunicorn[16388]:     return parse_func(self, stream, mimetype, content_length, options)
Sep 29 10:14:56 ip-10-2-1-136 gunicorn[16388]:   File "/home/ubuntu/ca/venv_dc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 131, in wrapper
Sep 29 10:14:56 ip-10-2-1-136 gunicorn[16388]:     return f(self, stream, *args, **kwargs)
Sep 29 10:14:56 ip-10-2-1-136 gunicorn[16388]:   File "/home/ubuntu/ca/venv_dc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 253, in _parse_multipart
Sep 29 10:14:56 ip-10-2-1-136 gunicorn[16388]:     form, files = parser.parse(stream, boundary, content_length)
Sep 29 10:14:56 ip-10-2-1-136 gunicorn[16388]:   File "/home/ubuntu/ca/venv_dc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 584, in parse
Sep 29 10:14:56 ip-10-2-1-136 gunicorn[16388]:     return self.cls(form), self.cls(files)
Sep 29 10:14:56 ip-10-2-1-136 gunicorn[16388]:   File "/home/ubuntu/ca/venv_dc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py", line 419, in __init__
Sep 29 10:14:56 ip-10-2-1-136 gunicorn[16388]:     for key, value in mapping or ():
Sep 29 10:14:56 ip-10-2-1-136 gunicorn[16388]:   File "/home/ubuntu/ca/venv_dc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 582, in <genexpr>
Sep 29 10:14:56 ip-10-2-1-136 gunicorn[16388]:     form = (p[1] for p in formstream if p[0] == "form")
Sep 29 10:14:56 ip-10-2-1-136 gunicorn[16388]:   File "/home/ubuntu/ca/venv_dc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 537, in parse_parts
Sep 29 10:14:56 ip-10-2-1-136 gunicorn[16388]:     for ellt, ell in self.parse_lines(file, boundary, content_length):
Sep 29 10:14:56 ip-10-2-1-136 gunicorn[16388]:   File "/home/ubuntu/ca/venv_dc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 480, in parse_lines
Sep 29 10:14:56 ip-10-2-1-136 gunicorn[16388]:     for line in iterator:
Sep 29 10:14:56 ip-10-2-1-136 gunicorn[16388]:   File "/home/ubuntu/ca/venv_dc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 761, in make_line_iter
Sep 29 10:14:56 ip-10-2-1-136 gunicorn[16388]:     for item in _iter_basic_lines():
Sep 29 10:14:56 ip-10-2-1-136 gunicorn[16388]:   File "/home/ubuntu/ca/venv_dc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 737, in _iter_basic_lines
Sep 29 10:14:56 ip-10-2-1-136 gunicorn[16388]:     new_data = next(_iter, "")
Sep 29 10:14:56 ip-10-2-1-136 gunicorn[16388]:   File "/home/ubuntu/ca/venv_dc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 681, in _make_chunk_iter
Sep 29 10:14:56 ip-10-2-1-136 gunicorn[16388]:     item = _read(buffer_size)
Sep 29 10:14:56 ip-10-2-1-136 gunicorn[16388]:   File "/home/ubuntu/ca/venv_dc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 943, in read
Sep 29 10:14:56 ip-10-2-1-136 gunicorn[16388]:     return self.on_disconnect()
Sep 29 10:14:56 ip-10-2-1-136 gunicorn[16388]:   File "/home/ubuntu/ca/venv_dc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 911, in on_disconnect
Sep 29 10:14:56 ip-10-2-1-136 gunicorn[16388]:     raise ClientDisconnected()
Sep 29 10:14:56 ip-10-2-1-136 gunicorn[16388]: werkzeug.exceptions.ClientDisconnected: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

Comment: Do you face the issue when running with gunicorn on your local?

Comment: @shoaib30 Nope can't reproduce this in local environment and in the prod server it occurs without a pattern.

Comment: Any specific configuration on the production server? nginx/ apache 
Could it actually be a network issue with the server that disconnected while processing the request?

Comment: Nope we are not using any reverse proxy. I don't see a reason why network would disconnect while processing the request

Comment: Another point worth a mention is that we use this server to perform long running task such as image processing. I am not sure if that makes a difference @shoaib30

Comment: I am not  sure if you'll get that error if the server runs out of resources. I would assume it won't have the resource to raise the exception either